# Heroku always runs assets:precompile with the production environment for Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have my Heroku environment set to staging but my assets are always compiled in the production environment.

Here's `heroku config`:

```
GEM_PATH            => vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
LANG                => en_US.UTF-8
PATH                => bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
RACK_ENV            => staging
```

I've added an exception to the `production.rb` file so I know which env it's running when compiling the assets. The server starts up just fine running `heroku run console` shows that I'm running staging.

It's just when running `assets:precompile` that it's always in production.

I'd be happy to post any other config file if required.

I can add that I'm running Rails 3.2.2 and the Cedar stack on heroku

---

Output from `heroku run rake about`:

```
About your application's environment
Ruby version             1.9.2 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version         1.3.7
Rack version             1.4
Rails version            3.2.2
JavaScript Runtime       therubyracer (V8)
Action Pack version      3.2.2
Active Support version   3.2.2
Middleware               Rack::Cache, ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, #, Rack::Runtime, Rack::Auth::Basic, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ActionDispatch::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
Application root         /app
Environment              staging
```

And running `heroku run rake assets:precompile` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

Should I just give up and email Heroku?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently I needed to [enable a plugin](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) to make it work.

Comment: i think the heroku guys should have specified this in the docs explicitly.

Comment: This plugin has now been deprecated - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `RAILS_ENV` to `staging` as well and see if that makes Heroku any happier.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the problem, but you can probably work around it. If public/assets/manifest.yml is present, the Heroku asset compiler won't run. You'll need to precompile assets yourself in this case, but it might work for you. Check out http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar for more info.

Comment: This would mean I'd have to check my assets in to my repo which I really don't want to do.

Comment: Or sync them up to S3 and include them in .gitignore. That's what we ended up doing; we use asset_sync and manually check in the manifest.yml file.