# How to access environment variables in coffeescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have the following line in a js.coffee.erb file in a Rails 3.2 app.

```
<%= ENV['MY_KEY'] %>
```

The app is deployed to Heroku and when I run heroku config I see MY_KEY listed with a value.

Yet when I inspect the compiled javascript file there is a gap where `ENV['MY_KEY']` value should be.

As far as I know it should be possible to access environment variables in a coffeescript asset. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Can you set and access the environment variable locally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku always runs assets:precompile with the production environment for Rails 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830244/heroku-always-runs-assetsprecompile-with-the-production-environment-for-rails-3)

Comment: @RossPenman if I render this env variable in a view it displays as expected.

Comment: @phoet this seems hopeful. However when I enable this plugin no assets are precompiled during deployment, causing the app the crash. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your app's config vars are not available in the environment by default. To allow this, you can enable the Heroku Labs feature [`user-env-compile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile).

Comment: thanks ryan, I have tried this but no success yet. Without the Lans feature, this config vars is available if I render in a view template, but is not available in the js file. When I activate the Labs feature, my app throws errors indicating that assets are not compiled. Is this expected behavior?